# An erroneous proof that any bounded function is integrable

Tags: real-analysis

I think I'm missing something obvious, but I just can't spot the flaw in the following proof:

Suppose $f:Q\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is bounded and nonnegative on a closed interval $Q$ in $\Bbb R$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, we show $U(f;P) - L(f;P) < \epsilon$, for some partition P of $Q$ (i.e. f is Riemann integrable).

Suppose the difference between the max and min of f on $Q$ is $D$. Then form a uniform partition of $Q$, called P, such that $x_{i+1}-x_i = \frac{\epsilon}{n\lceil D \rceil} $, n the size of the partition. Call the intervals $R_i$. Then $U(f;P) - L(f;P) = \sum_1^{n} (M_{R_i}(f) - m_{R_i}(f))(x_{i+1} - x_i) \le \sum_1^{n} D(x_{i+1} - x_i) = D n \frac{\epsilon}{n\lceil D \rceil} \le \epsilon$. Q.E.D.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: according to your summation index, we have $|Q|=\epsilon/\lceil D\rceil$, I'm not sure where that assumption comes from.

Comment: The sum of $x_{i+1} - x_i$ over the intervals of the partition is the length of $Q$.  This doesn't go to $0$.

Comment: To rephrase the previous comment, in your partition the sum of the intervals does not add up to the length of $Q$, but rather to $\epsilon/D$.

Comment: Yea ok I see... I guess it's impossible to construct a partition following this trail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have about $\frac{|Q|D^2}{\epsilon}$ small intervals of length $\frac{\epsilon}{D^2}$, on each of them the variation  is equal to $D$.

Hence $$U-L \le D\sum_{1}^{\left\lceil\frac{|Q|D^2}{\epsilon}\right\rceil}|x_{i+1}-x_i|=D\sum_{1}^{\left\lceil\frac{|Q|D^2}{\epsilon}\right\rceil}\frac{\epsilon}{D^2}\approx D|Q|. $$

Answer (score 1):

Each interval of the partition is $\frac{\epsilon}{n|D|}$ and there are $n$ of them. So the length of all the intervals is $n\frac{\epsilon}{n|D|}=\frac{\epsilon}{|D|}$, which should be the length of the interval $Q$ but instead becomes arbitrarily small.